# Compare every row to all other rows

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Assume I have a table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE events (
        event_id INTEGER,
        begin_date DATE,
        end_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (event_id));
```

With data like this:

```
INSERT INTO events SELECT 1 AS event_id,'2017-01-01'::DATE AS begin_date, '2017-01-07'::DATE AS end_date;
INSERT INTO events SELECT 2 AS event_id,'2017-01-04'::DATE AS begin_date, '2017-01-05'::DATE AS end_date;
INSERT INTO events SELECT 3 AS event_id,'2017-01-02'::DATE AS begin_date, '2017-01-03'::DATE AS end_date;
INSERT INTO events SELECT 4 AS event_id,'2017-01-03'::DATE AS begin_date, '2017-01-08'::DATE AS end_date;
INSERT INTO events SELECT 5 AS event_id,'2017-01-02'::DATE AS begin_date, '2017-01-09'::DATE AS end_date;
INSERT INTO events SELECT 6 AS event_id,'2017-01-03'::DATE AS begin_date, '2017-01-06'::DATE AS end_date;
INSERT INTO events SELECT 7 AS event_id,'2017-01-08'::DATE AS begin_date, '2017-01-09'::DATE AS end_date;
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
SELECT a.event_id, 
       COUNT (*) AS COUNT
  FROM events AS a
  LEFT JOIN events AS b
       ON a.begin_date < b.begin_date
          AND a.end_date > b.end_date
 GROUP BY a.event_id
 ORDER BY a.event_id ASC
```

With results like this:

```
*----------*--------*
| event_id |  count |
*-------------------*
|    1     |   3    |   
|    2     |   1    |   
|    3     |   1    |   
|    4     |   1    |   
|    5     |   3    |   
|    6     |   1    |   
|    7     |   1    |   
*----------*------- *
```

But with a window function (because it's much faster than the inequality join). Something like this, where I can compare the outer row to the inner rows.

```
SELECT a.event_id, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (a.begin_date < b.begin_date AND a.end_date > b.end_date) AS count
  FROM events AS a
 ORDER BY a.event_id ASC
```

Ideally this would work on both Postgres and Redshift.

Comment: What is your final requirement?

Comment: I mean what you do it for?

Comment: what'sthe expected result?..

Comment: Expected result is the output found under the line where I wrote, “With results like this”.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will get out of using a JOIN here. Even the window function idea would require a sort of implicit join since the window being compared would have to be a set of all other records.

Instead, consider using Postgres' daterange type. You can cast your begin and end dates into a range and check to see if the exclusive range from your left table contains the inclusive range of your right table:

```
SELECT t1.event_id, count(*) 
FROM events t1 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN events t2 
       ON daterange(t1.begin_date, t1.end_date, '()') @> daterange(t2.begin_date, t2.end_date, '[]') AND t1.event_id <> t2.event_id 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1;


 event_id | count
----------+-------
        1 |     3
        2 |     1
        3 |     1
        4 |     1
        5 |     3
        6 |     1
        7 |     1
```

The real question (and I don't know the answer) is that if all of this casting and "range includes" `@>` logic is more efficient then your inequality version. While the `Nested Loop Left Join` used here has a lower estimated rows, the `Total Cost` is about 33% higher.

I have a hunch if your data were stored as an inclusive daterange type, then the cost would be less as a cast wouldn't need to happen (although because we are comparing an inclusive range to an exclusive range then it may be a wash).